# elasticsearch why facet is so slow?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, facet

For below query without facet. it tooks 18 milli seconds.
But after adding facet it tooks 7408 milli seconds.

I am having 183M records.

Facets provide aggregated data based on a search query. right??? 
**Then why facet is taking so much time for doing aggregation on 40 records?**

Query Without facet: Tooks 18 Milli Seconds

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "country_raw": "united states"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "title_raw": "manager"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response for without facet query:

```
{
    "took": 18,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 40,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [ 
        ....
        ]
    }
}
```

Query With facet: : Tooks 7845 Milli Seconds

```
{
 "size": 0
 "facets": {
    "title_facet": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title_raw",
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "country_raw": "united states"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "title_raw": "manager"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Facet Query Response

```
{
    "took": 7408,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 40,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": [ ]
    },
    "facets": {
        "title_facet": {
            "_type": "terms",
            "missing": 0,
            "total": 40,
            "other": 0,
            "terms": [
                {
                    "term": "manager",
                    "count": 40
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try with "aggs" instead of "facet" ( i remember that facet are depreceated )

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [{
                            "term" : {
                                "country_raw" : "united states"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term" : {
                                "title_raw" : "manager"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "title_facet" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "title_raw",
                "size" : 5
            }
        }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_score" : "desc"
    }
}
```